# How to pass values from View to Controller method with javascript? in asp .net core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have some kind of messenger it have panel by side where I can see all my contacts. What I want is when i click on one of them to pass **phone number** and **Id** to my **Controller** to send message and save it in database.

Foreach prints all my contacts:

```
@foreach (var contact in Model.Contacts)
                {
                    <div class="chatperson" onclick="get_contact_number(@contact.PhoneNumber , @contact.ContactId)">
                        <div class="namechat">
                            <div class="pname">
                                @contact.Name
                                <a asp-action="ContactDetails" asp-route-id="@contact.ContactId" class=" glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></a>
                                <a asp-action="EditContact" asp-route-id="@contact.ContactId" class=" glyphicon glyphicon-pencil "></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lastmsg">@contact.PhoneNumber </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
```

In div I used JS method and passed there values:

```
function get_contact_number(contactNumber, contactId) {
    @Model.PhoneNr = contactNumber;
    @Model.ContactId = contactId;
}
```

In final i want to pass these values to my controller function

```
 public IActionResult SendMessage(MessengerViewModel model, string phoneNumber, string message)
    {
        var CurrentUserId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newMessage = new Message();

            newMessage.UserId = CurrentUserId;
            newMessage.ContactId = model.ContactId;
            newMessage.Body = model.MessageBody;
            newMessage.Date = DateTime.Now;
            newMessage.isDelivered = true;
            _messageService.AddMessage(newMessage);

            AtSmsSender smsSender = new AtSmsSender();
            message = model.MessageBody;
            phoneNumber = model.PhoneNr;
            smsSender.SendSms(phoneNumber, message);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Messenger");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Messenger");
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to read about AJAX requests

Comment: Why not just use a link?

Comment: `@Model.PhoneNr = contactNumber;` seems not a right thing. Note that `PhoneNr` value rendered in server side.

Comment: @StephenMuecke cuz no one likes when a whole page reloads when you just send a message in a chat?

Comment: @vasily.sib, I agree, but look at OP's code - they have `RedirectToAction()` which mean they want to redirect :)

Comment: Of course OP also has a pointless `if (ModelState.IsValid)` - it will never be invalid) so who knows what they want to do

Comment: @vasily.sib `RedirectToAction` is only for the time being coz now my app is in quiet raw and I will do a lot of refactoring, also still don't know how to make <div> reload which wont reload whole page

Comment: @DanielŽeimo, as I said before: you need to read about AJAX. In short: your JavaScript sends a request to server, receive new data and updates HTML elements right in your browser.

Comment: @vasily.sib yep, will read about it now

Answer (score 0):

you can do a ajax call from `get_contact_number` function. Something like the below code

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")',
    async:true,
    success:function(response){
        //Do Something With response object returned by your action
    }
});
```

Comment: if you are using jQuery and correctly install it in your app